# logical error, Binary Search for Strings in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to search a string in an array with the help of the binary search method but my code shows correct answers only for the strings (java at index 5, python at index 8, string at index 10, youtube at index 11). How I can fix this issue?

```
String array[] = {"java", "computer", "game",  "facebook",
                  "laptop", "chrome", "google", "youtube",
                  "mobile", "python", "string", "science"};

Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String to be search: ");
String item = input.nextLine();

int li = 0;                        // li => lower  index
int hi = array.length-1;           // hi => higher index
int mi = (li+hi)/2;                // mi => middle index
boolean found = false;
while (li<=hi) {
    if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) == 0) {
        System.out.println("item found at index: "+ mi);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
    else if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) == -1) { 
        hi = mi-1;
    }
    else {
        li= mi+1;
    }
    mi = (li+hi)/2;       
    }   
if (!found)
    System.out.println("Item not Found!!!");
```

Comment: Your strings aren't sorted to begin with. Binary search only works on sorted collections.

Answer (score 2):

There's just a minor problem.

In the `else if` condition, you should check `else if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) < 0)` instead of `else if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) == -1)`.

`compareTo` method returns 0 if match, or a value less than 0 is returned if the string is less than the other string (less characters) and a value greater than 0 if the string is greater than the other string (more characters).

Answer (score 0):

1. In binary search, always consider duplicates(unrelated to actual error in the code)

```java
        int li = 0;                        // li => lower  index
        int hi = array.length - 1;           // hi => higher index         // mi => middle index
        while (li < hi) {
            final int mi = li + (hi - li) / 2;
            if (array[mi].compareTo(item) < 0) { // move to right of mi
                li = mi + 1;
            } else {
                hi = mi; // move towards the first occurance of element
            }
        }

        if (item.equals(array[li])) {
            System.out.println("item found at index: " + li);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not Found!!!");
        }
```

The compareTo docs says

> the value {@code 0} if the argument string is equal to
>
> this string; a value less than {@code 0} if this string
>
> is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a
>
> value greater than {@code 0} if this string is
>
> lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (li<=hi) {
        if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) == 0) {
            System.out.println("item found at index: "+ mi);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (item.compareTo(array[mi]) < 0) {
            hi = mi-1;
        }
        else {
            li= mi+1;
        }
        mi = (li+hi)/2;
    }
```

Comment: Writing a code isn't enough, give some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
    String array[] = {"java", "computer", "game",  "facebook",
            "laptop", "chrome", "google", "youtube",
            "mobile", "python", "string", "science"};

Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a String to be search: ");
String item = input.nextLine();
int index = -1;
if (Arrays.asList(array).contains(item)) {
    index = Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(item);
    System.out.println("item found at index: "+ index);
}
else System.out.println("Item not Found!!!");
```